# unmarshalerDecoder: quantities must match the regular expression

Tags: kubernetes

When I am installing CoreDNS using this command ,by the way,the OS version is: CentOS 7.6 and Kubernetes version is: v1.15.2:

```
kubectl create -f coredns.yaml
```

The output is:

```
[root@ops001 coredns]# kubectl create -f coredns.yaml
serviceaccount/coredns created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:coredns created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:coredns created
configmap/coredns created
service/kube-dns created
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "coredns.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Resources: v1.ResourceRequirements.Requests: Limits: unmarshalerDecoder: quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$', error found in #10 byte of ...|__LIMIT__"},"request|..., bigger context ...|limits":{"memory":"__PILLAR__DNS__MEMORY__LIMIT__"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"70Mi"}},"secu|...
```

this is my coredns.yaml:

```
# __MACHINE_GENERATED_WARNING__

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
      kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
      addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
  name: system:coredns
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  - services
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
  name: system:coredns
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:coredns
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
      addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            upstream
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
            ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/name: "CoreDNS"
spec:
  # replicas: not specified here:
  # 1. In order to make Addon Manager do not reconcile this replicas parameter.
  # 2. Default is 1.
  # 3. Will be tuned in real time if DNS horizontal auto-scaling is turned on.
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kube-dns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
      annotations:
        seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: 'docker/default'
    spec:
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      serviceAccountName: coredns
      tolerations:
        - key: "CriticalAddonsOnly"
          operator: "Exists"
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      containers:
      - name: coredns
        image: gcr.azk8s.cn/google-containers/coredns:1.3.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: __PILLAR__DNS__MEMORY__LIMIT__
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 70Mi
        args: [ "-conf", "/etc/coredns/Corefile" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/coredns
          readOnly: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9153
          name: metrics
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - all
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      dnsPolicy: Default
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: coredns
            items:
            - key: Corefile
              path: Corefile
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/port: "9153"
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/name: "CoreDNS"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  clusterIP: 10.254.0.2
  ports:
  - name: dns
    port: 53
    protocol: UDP
  - name: dns-tcp
    port: 53
    protocol: TCP
  - name: metrics
    port: 9153
    protocol: TCP
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [coredns/deployment](https://github.com/coredns/deployment/tree/master/kubernetes) in your deployments there are fields like `limits {"memory":"__PILLAR__DNS__MEMORY__LIMIT__"`.

As described in the docs you can use `own script` to override some parameters while switching from kube-dns to COREDNS there is `deploy script`.

Installing [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/)

> In Kubernetes version 1.13 and later the CoreDNS feature gate is removed and CoreDNS is used by default.
>   So you can use your original installation and see default values in config map and deployment.

```
kubectl get configmap coredns -n kube-system -o yaml
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

From this error message

```
Error from server (BadRequest): 
error when creating "coredns.yaml": 
Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: 
v1.Deployment.Spec: 
v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v
1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: 
v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: 
v1.Container.Resources: 
v1.ResourceRequirements.Requests: Limits: unmarshalerDecoder: quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$', error found in #10 byte of ...|__LIMIT__"},"request|..., bigger context ...|limits":{"memory":"__PILLAR__DNS__MEMORY__LIMIT__"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"70Mi"}},"secu|...
```

This part is root-cause.

```
unmarshalerDecoder: 
quantities must match the regular expression 
'^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$'
```

What `quantities` are there?
Seems like

```
v1.ResourceRequirements.Requests: Limits:
```

So please, change `Requests.Limits` from `__PILLAR__DNS__MEMORY__LIMIT__` to other value.